# Vue callback after a click method is executed

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a list with @click events attached to its elements. I am dynamically creating some elements (using v-if) on these clicks and I need to execute some code over these dynamically created elements If I run it on the method that @click calls, the elements are not created yet, so I can't change them. How to call a function after vue has called this method?

My code:

```
<li class="food" @click="loadFood(food)">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use
`Vue.nextTick(function () {})`
to change elements
[more info](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-nextTick)